# Asp.net Core MVC Authorize Attribute not blocking

Tags: asp.net-core

Authorize attribute is not working. I am not logged in and it allows me to access this function.

i have played around with my Startup.cs attached at the bottom. Please help me get started with this. I have successfully used these methods on previous version of MVC, but I am not successful yet with MVC core.

After this I am looking to add roles. Any direction on where to start with that would be appreciated.
Thanks

```
public class SecurityAccessController : Controller
{
    private SecurityAccessDbContext SecurityAccessDbContext { get; set; }

    public SecurityAccessController([FromServices] SecurityAccessDbContext SecurityAccessDbContext)
    {
        this.SecurityAccessDbContext = SecurityAccessDbContext;
    }

    // GET: /<controller>/
    [Authorize]
    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }
}
```

This is my Start Up.cs
Updated as recommended by the below comment

```
 public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        // Add framework services.
        services.AddMemoryCache();
        services.AddSession();

        //Added
        services.AddBootstrapPagerGenerator(options => {options.ConfigureDefault();});

        //Database services
        services.AddEntityFrameworkSqlServer().AddDbContext<SecurityAccessDbContext>(options => { options.UseSqlServer(Configuration["ConnectionStrings:Accumatica"]); });
        services.AddEntityFrameworkSqlServer().AddDbContext<AcumaticaDbContext>(options => { options.UseSqlServer(Configuration["ConnectionStrings:Accumatica"]); });
        services.AddEntityFrameworkSqlServer().AddDbContext<RMADbContext>(options => { options.UseSqlServer(Configuration["ConnectionStrings:Accumatica"]); });
        services.AddEntityFrameworkSqlServer().AddDbContext<WarrantyDbContext>(options => { options.UseSqlServer(Configuration["ConnectionStrings:Accumatica"]); });
        services.AddEntityFrameworkSqlServer().AddDbContext<GenericDbContext>(options => { options.UseSqlServer(Configuration["ConnectionStrings:Accumatica"]); });
        services.AddEntityFrameworkSqlServer().AddDbContext<ApplicationIdentityDbContext>(options => { options.UseSqlServer(Configuration["ConnectionStrings:Accumatica"]); });

        services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, ApplicationRole>(options =>
        {
            options.Cookies.ApplicationCookie.LoginPath = "/Account/Login";
            options.Cookies.ApplicationCookie.AccessDeniedPath = "/Home/AccessDenied";
        })
        .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationIdentityDbContext>()
        .AddDefaultTokenProviders();

        services.AddMvc();

        services.AddTransient<IEmailSender, AuthMessageSender>();
    }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
    {
        loggerFactory.AddConsole(Configuration.GetSection("Logging"));
        loggerFactory.AddDebug();

        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            app.UseBrowserLink();
        }
        else
        {
            app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
        }

        app.UseStaticFiles();

        app.UseSession();

        app.UseIdentity();

        app.UseMvcWithDefaultRoute();
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the issue

the file launchsettings.json had

```
 "iisSettings": {
    "windowsAuthentication": true,
```

I changed to

```
  "iisSettings": {
    "windowsAuthentication": false,
```

Answer (score 4):

Add `Identity` before adding `Mvc`. Furthermore you don't need to add `Authorization` as that's already done when adding `Identity` as seen [here](https://github.com/aspnet/Identity/blob/8682cc74c87c847053cce151206fe06a999a3073/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity/IdentityServiceCollectionExtensions.cs#L75). You also can configure your identity options such as the login path, without needing configure `CookieAuthenticationOptions`. Instead you can configure it when adding `Identity`.

Here's a snippet of what the code could look like.

```
// Remove me
// services.AddAuthorization();

// Remove me too
// services.Configure<CookieAuthenticationOptions>(options =>
// ....

services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, IdentityRole>(options =>
{
    options.Cookies.ApplicationCookie.LoginPath = "/Account/Login";
    options.Cookies.ApplicationCookie.AccessDeniedPath = "/Home/AccessDenied";
    options.Cookies.ApplicationCookie.AutomaticChallenge = true;
    options.Cookies.ApplicationCookie.AutomaticAuthenticate = true;
})
.AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationIdentityDbContext>()
.AddDefaultTokenProviders();

services.AddMvc();
```

Comment: I tried your suggestion and the [Authorize] is still not working

Answer (score 0):

The above answer also helped me, but I can add that if you want the [AllowAnonymous] attribute to work you will also need to change the anonymousAuthentication to true:

```
  "iisSettings": {
"windowsAuthentication": false,
"anonymousAuthentication": true,
```